# Changing the position of html elements in Windows Forms WebBrowser

Tags: c#, html, forms

Is it possible to change the position of one html element in the Windows Forms WebBrowser Control? I already have this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("gpu_notice").Style = "display:none";
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("header").OuterHtml = "";
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ads").OuterHtml = "";
        // move element "the_game" here
    }
}
}
```

The next step would be moving an element...

Comment: You can inject javascript which in turn can modify the DOM http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153748/how-to-inject-javascript-in-webbrowser-control or you can just load dynamically created DOM directly into the control.

Comment: @Wobbles Just edited the question.

Comment: Where is `the_game` element defined? Odds are you can inject jquery to handle this if you include the jquery lib in your document and just use .append() and .detach()

Comment: @Wobbles Can you teach me how to do that?

Comment: After you read the above link about injecting javascript and have included the jquery library into your document, the code in javascript is as easy as `jQuery("#NodesToMove").detach().appendTo('#DestinationContainerNode')`

Comment: I will try it. Thanks.

Comment: @Wobbles Is there a way to do it without javascript?

Comment: edit your DOM virtually through string manipulation in c# then load that string into the browser control as needed using `webBrowser1.DocumentText = MYHTML`. not this will require browsing to blank before each DOM push

Comment: @Wobbles Man, thanks for your help, but I didn't understand very well...

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do, elaborate more, im not understanding why you want to move stuff around inside html in a control that is in a winform. sounds like if the content is that dynamic and your application is a true windows application that is should all just be handled in the winform itself and skip the browser control (its buggy and full of memory leaks anyway)

Comment: I just want to move a html element!

Comment: right, well you need to do that somehow right? If you don't want to do it by injecting javascript to move it then you must re-serve the updated document and change it in the markup each time. If you don't want to explain what the purpose is any further then there really isn't anything more I can do to help.

Comment: @Wobbles Ok, the purpose is to center a flash element.

Comment: Why not just do that through CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the_game element by adding `position` property to `Style` like this.

```
var game = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("the_game");            
game.Style += "position: absolute; top: 50px; right: 20px;";
```

I would recomend to read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) and get how to use this.

Comment: I can't change the Html of the page I'm using.

Comment: Then, get the element where you want to move the game element with get methods like `GetElementById()` and append the game's `OuterHtml`.
`dest.OuterHtml += game.OuterHtml`.

Comment: Thanks man, you helped me a lot! I have to put 0px in each top and right to allign the element to the center. Thanks!

Comment: Hey man, I know that's been a long, but can you help me on this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33465484/adding-a-image-element-to-a-webbrowser-control-page-existing-site/33465690#33465690.

Comment: Hi @DavidAmaral I've posted my answer to that question.