# Adding a image element to a webbrowser control page (existing site)

Tags: c#, forms

I'm trying to create an element with a image to a windows forms webbrowser control existing site. Then I want to move the created element to a certain position. I have this code, but it doesn't work.

```
 private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("gpu_notice").Style = "display:none"; 
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("header").OuterHtml = "";
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ads").OuterHtml = "";
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("the_game").Style += "position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px;";
        HtmlElement logo = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("logo");
        logo.SetAttribute("SRC", @"C:\Users\Susana\Documents\Projeto HaxballK\Design\Logo HK.png");
        webBrowser1.Document.Body.AppendChild(logo);
        logo.SetAttribute("float", "right");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the task inserting an element to an existing HTML document displayed with the `WebBrowser` class? If yes, then the steps could be (not tested, sorry)

1. download the document using `WebClient` as a HTML string
2. make `<body>` relative in the HTML string (insert `style='position: relative'` into the `<body>` element)
3. insert the element into the HTML string, just after `<body>`, make the element absolute (setting `style='position: absolute; left=...; right=...'`
4. set the modified HTML string into `DocumentText` property of the `WebBrowser` class

Comment: Yes, it is exacly what I'm looking for. I will try that, when you have time can you write a code with that instructions?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use "img" tag instead of "logo" and set the file path with using [file protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme).

```
HtmlElement logo = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("img");
logo.SetAttribute("SRC", @"file:///C:/Users/Susana/Documents/Projeto HaxballK/Design/Logo HK.png");
webBrowser1.Document.Body.AppendChild(logo);
logo.SetAttribute("float", "right");
```

**UPDATED**

If you want to add the image after all the JavaScript initializations have run, simply use one off `Timer`.

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new Timer();
void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // other processes

    timer.Interval = 1 * 1000 * 5; // 5 seconds
    timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
    timer.Start();
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer.Tick -= timer_Tick;

    HtmlElement logo = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("img");
    logo.SetAttribute("SRC", @"file:///C:/Users/Susana/Documents/Projeto HaxballK/Design/Logo HK.png");
    webBrowser1.Document.Body.AppendChild(logo);
    logo.SetAttribute("float", "right");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tryed and the logo appears when the page is loading but when the page completely loads, the image disappears.

Comment: Can't I use the DocumentCompleted event on this one?

Comment: @Khoury39 `DocumentCompleted` should be fine and this code just adds `<img src="file:///C:/Users/Susana/Documents/Projeto HaxballK/Design/Logo HK.png" float="right">`. I guess JavaScript might remove your logo so try my updated answer.

Comment: @Khoury39 can you post the website URL?

Comment: Of course. Haxball.com. It's a flash game, and I'm trying to make a offbrowser app, it removes all the elements except for the game. Now I'm trying to put a logo and a menu on the page...

Comment: @Khoury39 "the_game" element is hiding the logo image. Set `top: {logo hight}px;`